# Need a query to get one extract if key columns have same values and two columns are different

Tags: database

Database: Netezza (Let's say I have 10 rows in a source table)

I have source table where for e.g. Columns A, Column B, Column C, column D
has same values but different values in column E and column F in for example 6 rows.

And Also I have rows where values in Column A, Column B, column C, Column D, column E, Column

F are different.
Now I need a query which gives output for rows where above 4 columns
has same value should display in one line and two columns E and F with different values

Should display as single column concatenated (value of E, Value of F)

Select columnA, column B, column C, column D, column (E, F) from ;

And rows where values in Column A, Column B, column C, Column D, column E, column F are

Display in different rows as it is (since these records are unique).

I hope you guys understand my questions.

I need help to get output as mentioned above.

Comment: Please post your code so we can help you.

Comment: ...and some actual sample data and the expected results.

Comment: ... and what you have tried up to now, and why it fails.

Comment: Hi All,

Thank you for your reply.
Here is the details of my query.

Database: Netezza
Query Tool: TOAD
Key columns: department_description,page_description,group_code,season,field,action,userid, 

Value columns: current_value & previous_value 


Tried below query but it won't get me the list of values in CURRENT_VALUE & PREVIOUS_VALUE columns as comma separated values. It is just doing concatenating

Comment: select distinct DEPARTMENT,department_description,page_description,group_code,season,field,action,userid, 

case when  (DEPARTMENT,department_description,page_description,group_code,season,field,action,userid )  in 
(select DEPARTMENT,department_description,page_description,group_code,season,field,action,userid 
from sandbox.amdin.pg_pl_audit_log_src) then (current_value || ',' || current_value) 
else '0'
end as test,

Comment: case when  (DEPARTMENT,department_description,page_description,group_code,season,field,action,userid )  in 
(select DEPARTMENT,department_description,page_description,group_code,season,field,action,userid 
from sandbox.amdin.pg_pl_audit_log_src) then ( previous_value) || ',' || 
(previous_value)
else '0'
end as test2


from SANDBOX.ADMIN.PG_PL_AUDIT_LOG_SRC;

Comment: Added comments in pieces since it doesnot allow to post in once.